# Order of deployment of bundles

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have a question about OSGI bundles deployment.

I have 7 bundles which I need to deploy in a strict order otherwise I get no class found error. Part of the bundles are used as static libraries, part of them export OSGI services.

In OSGI applications how this problem is usually solved?

Answer (score 5):

This problem is solved by **not solving it** (at least, not in the way you have asked).

That is: don't have bundles that must to install/start in a strict order! This implies your bundles are very poorly designed. Instead, change your bundles so that they can start in any order.

If you have difficulties with this then please modify your question so that we can see why you think you need the start ordering.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your issue correctly, it is just a matter of providing the correct dependencies chain to be resolved by OSGi.
Your libraries should export packages that your services will import.

If **BundleA** requires classes from **BundleB** and **OtherBundle**, adding [Import-Package](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Import-Package) and [Export-Package](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Export-Package) metadata in the MANIFEST.MF of all bundles should be sufficient.

**BundleA** MANIFEST.MF

> Import-Package: my.required.package.from.b, other.package.in.b, other.package

**BundleB** MANIFEST.MF

> Export-Package: my.required.package.from.b, other.package.in.b

**OtherBundle** MANIFEST.MF

> Export-Package: other.package

Then install all bundles, they will be in `INSTALLED` state. Start the main one (**BundleA** in this example).
OSGi will resolve all dependencies (just be careful not to have cycles) and bundles will go in `RESOLVED` state (dependencies available) and then `ACTIVE`.

You don't need to manually add those dependencies, tools like [maven-bundle-plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) can be easily configured.

Also this question [What is the natural start order for package-dependent OSGI bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11574166/423955) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the best approach, as Neil Bartlett mentioned, is avoiding it. However sometimes ordering the start of the bundles is necessary. Even using Equinox or Felix you can have it using [bundle start-level](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/). It will ensure that your bundles will start in a specific order.

"A start level is associated with every bundle. The start level is a positive integer value that controls the order in which bundles are activated/started. Bundles with a low start level are started before bundles with a high start level. Hence, bundles with the start level, 1, are started first and bundles belonging to the kernel tend to have lower start levels, because they provide the prerequisites for running most other bundles." - [Red Hat JBoss Fuse Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/DeployBundle-Lifecycle.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using start levels doesn't prevent you from having problems. The startup ordering within a start level is undefined, and you can't break cycles.